# RevTeX-4.2 and dcolumn : align decimal with integer numbers

Tags: tables, alignment, dcolumn

I am creating a table which has to be aligned in the decimal point. I am using the `RevTeX-4.2` class and the `dcolumn` package.

My code is the following

```
\documentclass[reprint,
               superscriptaddress,
               showkeys,
               nofootinbib,
               amsmath,amssymb,
               aps,
               prc,
               floatfix,
               ]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
% table caption is above the table
\caption{\label{tab:kernels}List of the fission kernels that were able to be extracted with a statistical uncertainty less than $30\%$.}
\begin{ruledtabular}
%
\begin{tabular}{dddd}
%
%header
%
{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Fission kernel}} & {}\\
{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(meV)}          & {}\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$E_n$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Present work} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Bouland et al.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Difference}\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(eV)} & {} & {} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{($\%$)}\\
\hline
   1.06\footnotemark[1] &   0.00059(3)  &   0.00063 &   -6\\%STAT
  20.4\footnotemark[2]  &   0.027(2)    &   0.019   &   35\\
  38.4\footnotemark[2]  &   0.0078(16)  &   0.0043  &   59\\
  66.6\footnotemark[1]  &   0.021(5)    &   0.016   &   25\\%STAT
  72.8\footnotemark[1]  &   0.044(8)    &   0.041   &    8\\%STAT
 152.0\footnotemark[1]  &   0.099(6)    &   0.094   &    6\\%STAT
 260.5\footnotemark[1]  &   0.048(14)   &   0.038   &   26\\%STAT
 287.0\footnotemark[1]  &   0.30(9)     &   0.30    &   -2\\%STAT
 405.0\footnotemark[1]  &   0.33(8)     &   0.36    &   -8\\%STAT
 743.1\footnotemark[2]  &   0.017(3)    &   0.040   &   -82\\
 750.1\footnotemark[2]  &   8.0(9)      &   6.9     &   16\\
 778.1\footnotemark[1]  &   0.020(4)    &   0.019   &    3\\%STAT
 783.1\footnotemark[1]  &   3.8(6)      &   3.8     &    1\\%STAT
 790.5\footnotemark[1]  &   5.5(8)      &   5.7     &   -3\\%STAT
1402\footnotemark[1]    &   10.3(20)    &   9.6     &    7\\%STAT
1842\footnotemark[1]    &   8.2(8)      &   7.7     &    6\\%STAT
1902\footnotemark[1]    &   3.2(6)      &   2.8     &   12\\%STAT
1917\footnotemark[1]    &   20(3)       &   21      &   -4\\%STAT
1948\footnotemark[1]    &   7.5(14)     &   6.0     &   22\\%STAT
1955\footnotemark[1]    &   18(3)       &   20      &   -13\\%STAT
2033\footnotemark[2]    &   10.3(25)    &   6.6     &   43\\
2698\footnotemark[1],\footnotemark[3]   &   82(10)      &   77      &    6\\%STAT - ENERGY
6551\footnotemark[1]    &  12.5(2.2)   &   -       &    -\\
7508\footnotemark[1]    &   64(19)     &   -       &    -\\
8098 \footnotemark[1]   &  111(27)     &   -       &    -\\
\end{tabular}
%
%
\end{ruledtabular}
\footnotetext[1]{Agreement within statistical uncertainties}
\footnotetext[2]{Discrepancy beyond statistical uncertainties}
\footnotetext[3]{Resonance energy was found higher by $4$ eV}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

and the output can be seen below

[image]

I guess the issue here is that I am trying to align decimal numbers with integer ones. The `dcolumn` package should take car of non-decimal number, according to [its documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/dcolumn.pdf) so I don't understand the issue... Could be the parentheses, but I need them, so a workaround this would be great!

Comment: Would switching to `siunitx` be an option?

Comment: the alignment of integer and decimals is handled, see your third column where each integer is aligned with the floating point as if there is an invisible `.0` after the integer. The alignment in the other columns is off due to the parenthesis and superscripts, which require special casing not to confuse dcolumn. basically you want `\rlap(10)` to hide the (10) from the alignment. or right `18.0(3)` rather than `18(3)`

Comment: @leandriis : Thank you very much for your comment but the journal I want to submit this, recommends `dcolumn`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : Thank you very much for your comment. I tried using `\rlap` but what I get is a parenthesis that is drawn on the number. In addition `18.0(3)` had a different meaning than `18(3)` in the scope of the manuscript. Any other idea?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I was just forgetting the braces! Never mind!!

Comment: @Thanos or rather you were too polite to mention, but I told you the wrong syntax, with missing braces, `\rlap{(10)}` sorry:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : No worries! Since your recommendation worked, is it possiblt to write an answer so that there are alternatives? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I introduced a new column with digit alignment and introduced `\rlap` tag for footnote numbers, here is the modified tags:

```
\documentclass[reprint,
               superscriptaddress,
               showkeys,
               nofootinbib,
               amsmath,amssymb,
               aps,
               prc,
               floatfix,
               ]{revtex4}

\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\newcolumntype{z}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
% table caption is above the table
\caption{\label{tab:kernels}List of the fission kernels that were able to be extracted with a statistical uncertainty less than $30\%$.}
\begin{ruledtabular}
%
\begin{tabular}{z{4,2}z{2,5}z{2,5}z{2}}
%
%header
%
{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Fission kernel}} & {}\\
{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(meV)}          & {}\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$E_n$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Present work} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Bouland et al.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Difference}\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(eV)} & {} & {} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{($\%$)}\\
\hline
   1.06\rlap{\footnotemark[1]} &   0.00059(3)  &   0.00063 &   -6\\%STAT
  20.4\rlap{\footnotemark[2]}  &   0.027(2)    &   0.019   &   35\\
  38.4\rlap{\footnotemark[2]}  &   0.0078(16)  &   0.0043  &   59\\
  66.6\rlap{\footnotemark[1]}  &   0.021(5)    &   0.016   &   25\\%STAT
  72.8\rlap{\footnotemark[1]}  &   0.044(8)    &   0.041   &    8\\%STAT
 152.0\rlap{\footnotemark[1]}  &   0.099(6)    &   0.094   &    6\\%STAT
 260.5\rlap{\footnotemark[1]}  &   0.048(14)   &   0.038   &   26\\%STAT
 287.0\rlap{\footnotemark[1]}  &   0.30(9)     &   0.30    &   -2\\%STAT
 405.0\rlap{\footnotemark[1]}  &   0.33(8)     &   0.36    &   -8\\%STAT
 743.1\rlap{\footnotemark[2]}  &   0.017(3)    &   0.040   &   -82\\
 750.1\rlap{\footnotemark[2]}  &   8.0(9)      &   6.9     &   16\\
 778.1\rlap{\footnotemark[1]}  &   0.020(4)    &   0.019   &    3\\%STAT
 783.1\rlap{\footnotemark[1]}  &   3.8(6)      &   3.8     &    1\\%STAT
 790.5\rlap{\footnotemark[1]}  &   5.5(8)      &   5.7     &   -3\\%STAT
1402\rlap{\footnotemark[1]}    &   10.3(20)    &   9.6     &    7\\%STAT
1842\rlap{\footnotemark[1]}    &   8.2(8)      &   7.7     &    6\\%STAT
1902\rlap{\footnotemark[1]}    &   3.2(6)      &   2.8     &   12\\%STAT
1917\rlap{\footnotemark[1]}    &   20(3)       &   21      &   -4\\%STAT
1948\rlap{\footnotemark[1]}    &   7.5(14)     &   6.0     &   22\\%STAT
1955\rlap{\footnotemark[1]}    &   18(3)       &   20      &   -13\\%STAT
2033\rlap{\footnotemark[2]}    &   10.3(25)    &   6.6     &   43\\
2698\rlap{\footnotemark[1]},\rlap{\footnotemark[3]}   &   82(10)      &   77      &    6\\%STAT - ENERGY
6551\rlap{\footnotemark[1]}    &  12.5(2.2)   &   -       &    -\\
7508\rlap{\footnotemark[1]}    &   64(19)     &   -       &    -\\
8098 \rlap{\footnotemark[1]}   &  111(27)     &   -       &    -\\
\end{tabular}
%
%
\end{ruledtabular}
\footnotetext[1]{Agreement within statistical uncertainties}
\footnotetext[2]{Discrepancy beyond statistical uncertainties}
\footnotetext[3]{Resonance energy was found higher by $4$ eV}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that I don't have have the class file what you used, so I used `revtex4` instead of yours.