# Align Decimals in table with additional integer and parenthesis

Tags: tables, alignment, tabulary, dcolumn

I am creating a table and am aligning the numbers in the column with the package \dcolumn.
In "normal" cases this works, but not if I add parenthesis.

This is a minmal example that shows my problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot,fleqn]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lD{.}{.}{3}l}

0   & 100(1) &  0.80(6) \\
1   & 71.9(8)&  0.797(6)\\
2   & 7.8(6) &  0.788(6)\\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way I can align the integer in the middle row aswell?

[image: My result]

Some things I tried:

- Chancing the "3" in the line with \begin{tabular} to different integers
- using \rlap()
- following some incomplete instructions given here:
  [RevTeX-4.2 and dcolumn : align decimal with integer numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509452/revtex-4-2-and-dcolumn-align-decimal-with-integer-numbers)

...but obviously nothing worked...
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With `siunitx` instead of `dcolumn`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot,fleqn]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=3.1(1)]S[table-format=1.3(1)]}
0   & 100(1) &  0.80(6) \\
1   & 71.9(8)&  0.797(6)\\
2   & 7.8(6) &  0.788(6)\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately with other packages I use (give to me as a template) there is an error. Is there a way to keep the package dcolumns?

Comment: @HansR: Which error message specifically do you get? Coudld you narrow down the issue to a MWE that allows others to reproduce this error? Probably there is a way to make `siunitx` cooperate with your template.

Comment: The Error was : "! Package siunitx Error: Package 'SIunits' incompatible."

If I delete the  line ```\usepackage[amssymb,thinspace]{SIunits}``` it works as shown by your answer. I will ask my professor if it is neccessary. If not, I got an answer :) 
It does work now!